# Explicitly check React Component received necessary props?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

React Component may receive a set of parameters (props) from caller (parent). Is there a mechanism to check that only necessary props was passed (not more and not less)?

I know that we can check this things in constructor at runtime but it's a waste of resources. Is there way to check this things at **build time?**

Comment: if thats the case why not send only needed props to your child component rather than sending all props?

Comment: Sure. I think you mean filtering. No. The question is "Can React help me identify mismatch between **props send to component** and **props component actually need**?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [proptypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

Below example taken from above link:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

In the above example, whereever you use `Greeting` component you should send a prop `name` which is of type `string`. or else your application will fail to run.

This check will be done at development phase itself so that we can make required changes to send the correct props

Comment: With the notion that these checks are only performed in the browser in development mode, not at build time (as the question is about).

Comment: Yes. I have to edit answer saying its only at development mode.